# owl carousel 2 urlhash transition issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I am having a transition issue when sliding my carousel using prev button between slide 1 and 4.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdw714pL/2/)

Keep clicking prev and you will see the issue.

I have a feeling that **data-hash** attribute is causing this issue.

HTML

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item" data-hash="1">1</div>
  <div class="item" data-hash="2">2</div>
  <div class="item" data-hash="3">3</div>
  <div class="item" data-hash="4">4</div>
</div>
<div class="links">
  <a href="#1">1</a>
  <a href="#2">2</a>
  <a href="#3">3</a>
  <a href="#4">4</a>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items:1,
        loop:true,
        nav:true,
        navText:['<span class="prev">prev</span>','<span class="next">next</span>'],
        margin:10,
        URLhashListener:true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the data-hash parts in all the four divs and it will start working

Comment: But I need them in order to use buttons 1,2,3,4 to navigate through the slider